# Change date of POSIXct variable based on other columns in R

Tags: posixct

Is there a way to change the date of a *dttm* column based on the values from other columns? The time in the "Date_Time" column is correct, but the dates need to be changed to match those in the column "Date" (or from all three columns "Year", "Month", and "Day").

This is likely close to what I need to do, but it gives me this error:

```
library(lubridate)
    df$new <- with(df, ymd_hm(sprintf('%04d%02d%02d', Year, Month, day, Time))) #'Time' is new character column of just time component from 'Date_Time'
    
    # Not sure what this means..
    invalid format '%04d'; use format %s for character objects

        > head(df,5)
    # A tibble: 5 x 5
      Date       Year  Month   Day Date_Time          
      <chr>      <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
    1 2020-11-14 2020     11    14 1899-12-31 10:46:00
    2 2020-11-14 2020     11    14 1899-12-31 10:57:00
    3 2020-11-14 2020     11    14 1899-12-31 09:16:00
    4 2012-8-11  2012      8    11 1899-12-31 14:59:00
    5 2012-8-11  2012      8    11 1899-12-31 13:59:00
```

Comment: I've tried converting the time variable back into a character string on it's own then re-combining everything and converting it back into a date-time, but got NA with library(lubridate)
with(df, ymd_h(paste(Year, Month, Day, Time, sep= ' ')))

Answer (score 0):

First update the `Date` column to be a date. Then use `lubridate` to assign that date to the `Date_Time` column:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
lubridate::date(df$Date_Time) <- df$Date
```

And if necessary, update the timezone to whatever if needs to be:

```
attr(df$Date_Time, "tzone") <- "Europe/Paris" # Update timezone
```